# slideToggle with floating items

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

Not the best title but I had no idea how to describe my problem in a few words. I have six floating items, each with a description. I'm using `slideToggle` to hide and show the description of each item. The problem is that the description `div` is wider (100%) than the item it corresponds to (30%) and I need to show this description between the six items (there are 3 on a row). Now, every time I show a description the floating items are... well, not floating anymore because of the wider div.

I tried to use `position: absolute;` on the description div, but then the rest of the floating items covered the description.

It's a lot of code (mostly text) so I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YdFdz/). This might not be the best solution to get to the result I want, so any idea on how to solve or re-code this would be helpful.

In case my explanation or the fiddle is not clear enough I also have a screenshot of the design I'm trying to code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd29U/**

Your problems happened because you put the `container-text` after each individual `container-services dev`.

I first put three buttons in a row, and after that the three corresponding texts.
JavaScript checks which button is pressed and handles accordingly.
(HTML, JavaScript and CSS are all changed)

---

**EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/n5LjJ/**

All the `container-services` now start with the class "default", which gets switched to "active" when you click on it.
In the CSS, I created two sub-classes, each with their own background-color and border-color. You can of course change those and add whatever style-rules you like.

I removed the `activeButton`-var, and check for the active-class instead.

The only possible downside of that, is that you have to put in this line:
`$('.container-services').removeClass('active').addClass('default');`, which checks every `container-services`-element for the active-class.
If you would store the classname of the active button in the `activeButton`-var, you would only have to change the active-class of that one element back to "default".
You won't notice it, but strictly speaking, more code needs to be executed now, which is of course less optimal..

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the explanation. Could you please explain a bit further the jQuery you used to identify the 'active' button? I want to customize the button it its active state (probably best done with classToggle).

Comment: I edited my answer (don't know if you get an email or anything about that)

Comment: Thanks for helping, I didn't see the edited answer, I get notifications only on new comments and replies.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Oh btw, I added a `onmousedown="return false"` in the HTML on all the buttons, so you can't select the text on those elements (doesn't work on touch platforms like smartphone and tablet though)